# Interactive UIView behind UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I've been struggling with a `UIScrollView` related problem for about a week now and frankly I can't seem to solve it.

This is that I want to accomplish:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4aHK.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7msM.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNinp.jpg

I want the `UITableView's` content to slide on top of the [LSWeekView](https://github.com/LumenSpark/LSWeekView)

In my first iteration I got everything working by adding the `LSWeekView` as a subview to the `UITableView` and making it fixed to the top. This worked really well up until some recent changes.

The `UITableView` is now wrapped in a `UIPageViewController` which makes it possible for the user to swipe from one day to another. The problem that then occurs is that the `LSWeekView` is now sliding together with the `UITableView` and there're also multiple instances of the `LSWeekView`.

What I've tried so far:

1. A `UIView` with an `LSWeekView` and a `UITableView` (wrapped in `UIPageViewController`) as subviews. By using the UITableView's delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll`: I was able to adjust the origin the `UITableView`. The problem with this solution is that I have to override the `contentOffset` of the UITableView so that it doesn't scroll when adjusting the origin. Unfortunently this introduced some problems with the momentum/deceleration of the `UITableView`.
2. A `UIScrollView` with an `LSWeekView` and a `UITableView` (wrapped in `UIPageViewController`) as subviews. By subclassing the UITableView and the `UIScrollView` I was able to allow simultaneous panning. But again I had to override the `contentOffset` so that the `UITableView` didn't scroll when panning in the `UIScrollView`, so basically the same problem with this solution as well.

Maybe the solutions I've come up with is the way to go and I just have to make them work by applying my own deceleration and such. But I feel like there should be a better way.

Hopefully you guys can help me get back on track with some ideas on how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Here is a simpler approach which worked for me for a similar requirement.

Add the LSWeekView to as a subview to your parent view.
Add the table view too as as subview to the the same parentView but above the LSWeekview in hierarchy.
Set the tableView's contentInset

```
 [tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(requiredHeight, 0, 0, 0)];
```

And set the tableView's backgroundColor to clearColor.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems that it's not possible to interact with the LSWeekView since it's covered by the UITableView. Although pointInside: withEvent: seems to fix that. The thing is that I'm not sure how I would override the pointInside: withEvent: method on the UIPageViewController's subviews, since they are private? I'm going to explore this solution a bit more.

Comment: Try Subclassing your tableView and override the following method with this

`- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}`

A pageViewController has an array of viewController Objects. So every viewControllers respective view is the superView to the tableView and the LSWeekView. So I don't think its private.

Comment: That doesn't work, it's not the table view that is blocking the interaction. I think it's the scrollView of the pageViewController and the scrollView is private? I might be able to delegate the touch events directly to the weekView though. I going to give it a shot when I arrive at work.

Comment: The view hierarchy looks like this: UIView => [LSWeekView, UIScrollView => [UITableView, UITableView, UITableView]]. In other words I can send touches from UITableView to the UIScrollView but not from the UIScrollView to the LSWeekView since the UIScrollView in the UIPageViewController is private and so I can't subclass it. Am I right?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Much appreciated, check my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding the `LSWeekView` on top of the `UIPageViewController` and then resizing the `LSWeekView` when the `UITableView` triggered `scrollViewDidScroll:`.

layoutSubviews:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetMake(100, 0, 0, 0);
```

scrollViewDidScroll:

```
CGRect frame = self.weekView.frame;
frame.size.height = 100 - scrollView.contentOffset.y;
if (frame.size.height < 0) {
    frame.size.height = 0;
}
self.weekView.frame = frame;
```

Thanks for the help @NavinDev.